# cannot make the URLrewritng to work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to implement URL rewriting but I cannot.The purpose is to build a RESTful API based on this tutorial here [tutorial](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/)

Before posting I consulted this topic also here [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2/5758551#5758551)

I have tried many things but with no result. I will go straight into the details.
I am building a web app where appointments are stored and there is the admin section of it where the user can see these appointments.(everything is done locally)
As such I have placed an .htaccess file in the admin folder of the app:
    C:\Apache24\htdocs\Appointments\Administrator

The code in .htaccess is this:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule .* ./test.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

The above code is just for testing...in other words if a user requests a page that does not exist test.php should appear in his browser-of course I have created such page and it is in the admin folder as well.

So if the user types in the address bar 
    `http://localhost/Appointments/Administrator/calen`
Then test.php should appear...and the problem is it does not because of course there is not a page with the name calen.

In addition to the above I went to httpd.config and unccomented this line
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so something which I think(unless I am wrong) activates the rewrite module

**So what can be wrong here?**

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule .* ./test.php [L,R]`

Comment: Does the "Appointments" or "Administrator" folders exist? Is there another htaccess file there?

Comment: @jon Lin Of course and the above mentioned folders exist...if a request a PHP file in the above folders(http://localhost/Appointments/Administrator/calendar.php) there is no problem for the browser serving them to me and there is no other htaccess file in them

Comment: @anubhava I tried your code but it did not have any results.

Comment: You restart apache after uncommenting the rewrite module line in httpd.conf?

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou: Are you sure your .htaccess is enabled?

Comment: @JonLin Yes I did the restart.Do you think that the c in the right of the mod_rewrite in the if statement plays a role here?If for example a special rewrite  module must be installed and it is not in my case...I m just thinking,nothing else.

Comment: @anubhava what do you mean if I am sure. I have uncommented the proper line in httpd.config(enabling mod_rewrite in other words) and I have added the .htaccess extension to the text file where the code is located.Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Verify if your `.htaccess` is enabled by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: @anubhava you mean something like that:ahahahaha
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* ./test.php [L,R]
</IfModule>

Comment: yes, does it result in 500 error?

Comment: @anubhava NO I DO NOT GET 500 error.I see the message that I saw before putting garbage text...meaning Not Found...The requested URL...was not found on this server

Comment: Well that means your .htaccess is NOT ENABLED. You need to enable it from httd.conf and restart Apache

Comment: what line exactly in httpd.conf is responsible for enabling htaccess...can you help me on that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45313/discussion-between-dimitris-papageorgiou-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need correct `RewriteBase` here. Try this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase /Appointments/Administrator/

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule ^ test.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: yes the above worked but with a slight modification-the syntax of the rewrite rule had to be left unchanged,meaning:RewriteRule .* ./test.php [L]